# Java loading a jar & then using it's data (variables & methods & classes)?

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have a `JFrame` window that downloads a jar file & then starts it so the jar will execute inside the `JFrame` and show inside it too.

But the whole idea is, instead of letting users download the new jar version it will automatically grab (download) the new jar with the same launcher.

Now I don't want to let them download it many times everytime, might cause bandwidth lose etc, and instead I thought of having version checking.

Java will first check if the folder MyJar exists at the home folder of the OS, along with the jar file, if yes it will access the jar files data and check if the string `version` equals to the new version that I will buffer before it from the website, if not equal, download a new jar file into that folder. and then start it.

if jar version equals it will process and launch that jar.

This is the code I use currently to load form the web:

```
String jarURL = "http://someurl/game.jar"; // example broke the link from stackoverflow
String mainClass = "main";
ClassLoader clientClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
                                    new URL[] { new URL(jarURL) });
Class<?> clientClass = clientClassLoader.loadClass(mainClass);
this.loader = (Applet) clientClass.newInstance();
```

And I want to do something like this, for example in that jar I have a public variable named `version`, so I can access `this.loader.getClass(main.class).version` <- I know it's not done that way but just an example.

How can I do this?

Comment: you cannot do .getClass() without downloading the .jar first, so your logic is flawed. If you want to get the version comparison using the web site before downloading, use HTTP conditional get or similar.

Comment: Doesn't this temporary downloads the jar & uses it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @eis I want to use variables & methods from that jar, thats it. String myVar = thisjar.version; <- Inside the jar, public String version = "1";

Comment: This **really** seems to be one of the cases for which [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) was ***designed!***